# Visual Studio 2015 Browse to find source dialog not appearing, and not stepping into disassembly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, debug-symbols

Three problems I am having while debugging in Visual Studio 2015 recently are driving me nuts.

1) When debugging native c++, and trying to step into (F11) a native function for which symbols are apparently not loaded, it simply steps over it instead, unless I drop down to disassembly debugging prior to the function call. This happens despite having the Debugging->General option "Show disassembly if source is not available" explicitly checked, as well as "Enable Just My Code" unchecked.

2) It used to be that when attempting to step into a function for which symbols and source are not available, I'd get a dialog box asking me to browse for the missing source code. This is no longer happening either.

3) Last but not least, for the functions in I'm trying to step into, they exist in a static lib outside the solution, and I do indeed have full source code and symbols for it on my drive, but I cannot debug it properly, despite the fact that I originally built the external source code myself with full symbols, and I never moved the built code to a different location. If I manage to step into the disassembly of the functions, I can see the function names properly in the callstack window, but I cannot get back to source code and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to tell Visual Studio that yes, I have the source code, and yes I know exactly where it is.

For reference, here are my debugging options:

[image]

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: All of these questions are closely related and I think it's more than appropriate for them to be combined into a single post.

Comment: Yes, they are all related, but they require different answers IMO

Comment: I have the distinct feeling that there's one solution for all of them, probably one setting somewhere.